# Mathematical Induction proof using the transitivity of the non-strict inequality

Tags: analysis

Having proven that $\{a_n\}$ is an increasing sequence and that $\{b_n\}$ is a decreasing sequence how do you prove using mathematical induction that $a_n\leq a_m$ for all natural numbers $n < m$ and that $b_n\geq b_m$ for all natural numbers $n < m$. I am told that this result follows easily using the transitivity of the non-strict inequalities. However, I have not been able to complete the inductive proof using the transitivity of the non-strict inequalities. Please explain.

Comment: The essential rule you need is that $n\leq m$ if any only if there is a $k\in\mathbb N$ such that $n+k=m$. Then the induction is on $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you are given that $a_i \le a_{i+1}$ for all $i$. From this, you can use induction that for any $m$ and $n$, if $n<m$ then $a_n \le a_m$ as follows:

First, note that if $n<m$, then $m=n+k$ for some $k>0$. So now we're going to prove that for all $k>0$: $a_n \le a_{n+k}$:

Base: $k=1$. Well, we know that $a_n \le a_{n+1}$. Check!

Step: We assume (inductive hypothesis) that $a_n \le a_{n+k}$, and now we want to show that $a_n \le a_{n+k+1}$. Well, we know that $a_{n+k} \le a_{n+k+1}$. But the inductive hypothesis tell us that $a_n \le a_{n+k}$. So, bu transitivity of the $\le$ we thus get that indeed $a_n \le a_{n+k+1}$. Check!

Answer (score 0):

HINT (first part, second part follows a similar pattern):

Base case: $a_n \leq a_{n+1}$ holds as $\{ a_k \}$ is an increasing sequence. Assume it holds for some $m$, then: $a_n \leq a_{n+m}$. What is the relation between $a_{n+m}$ and $a_{n+m+1}$? What is the relation between $a_n$ and $a_{n+m+1}$?

Answer (score 0):

Transitivity means that we can write down logical expressions of the form

$a \le b \le c$

as shorthand - any number to the left of any other number is less than or equal to that number. Call this an inequality chain of length 3. Given any sequence $c_n$ there are many finite subsequences, such as

$c_5, c_6, c_7, c_8$

and corresponding inequality chains

$c_5 \le  c_6 \le  c_7 \le  c_8$

which may be true or false.

Looking at our sequence $a_n$, let us prove that all the finite $\le$ chains are true. For length $2$ it follows from our assumption that the sequence is increasing. Assume it is true for all chains of length $n$, and consider any $n + 1$ chain:

$a_p \le a_{p+1} ... \le a_{p+n}$

but that is shorthand for $a_p \le a_{p+1} ... \le a_{p+(n-1)}$ AND $a_{p+(n-1)} \le a_{p+n}$

By the inductive hypothesis the left side is true, and the right side is true,  again, since the sequence $a_n$ is increasing.

In actual practice, now that you understand this, you might say

Let $a_0 \le a_1 \le a_2 \le ... \le a_n ...$ be an increasing sequence.